# Mostrar resultado de un api en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

Necesito parsear un json para poder manipular la informacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito poder manipular la informacion, al filtrar el resultado me devuelve un objeto json
este es mi codigo

```
const url = 'https://servexusinc.com/api/Model/getTestData';

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {



        document.getElementById("element");
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.filter(function (item) { 


            return item.Id == element.value;


        }));

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que tal si usas el comando [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Comment: Buenas compañero, puedes usar tu data como si fuera un array de objetos, por lo que podrías acceder directamente a las propiedades y asignarla a una tabla o un formulario por ejemplo. Saludos!

Comment: Como lo podria hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Pudes utilizar el siguiente alcance si lo que quieres es manipular la información filtrada en el HTML:

```js
function consultarPersona(id) {
  const personas = [
    { id: 1, nombre: 'Lucía', apellido: 'Gomez' },
    { id: 2, nombre: 'sofía', apellido: 'Martinez' }
  ]

  const persona = personas.filter(d => d.id === id)[0];
  return persona;
}

window.onload = () => {
  const persona = consultarPersona(1);
  document.querySelector('#nombre').value = persona.nombre;
  document.querySelector('#apellido').value = persona.apellido;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input id="nombre" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Apellido</label>
    <input id="apellido" type="text">
  </p>
</form>
```